# How to hide html page based on Geo location..?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Consider that iam having an html page ..

I would like to show that page to users not from India(IN) and display the page to users from other countries ...

Like https://einthusan.tv..

Please any one  help me with a complete working code ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city, response.country);
    if(response.country == 'KR'){
        //handle your logic here
        alert('You can not see this content');
        //window.location.href = '/yourlink';
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

```js
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city, response.country);
    if(response.country == 'KR'){
        //handle your logic here
        alert('You can not see this content');
        //window.location.href = '/yourlink';
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```